# How to count the total records related to another table?

Tags: sql

I have a table called `discursion` that stores all my users' questions:

| ID_Discursion | TEXT_Discursion |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | My question is... |
| 2 | bla bla bla bla |

In addition, I have another table that stores user responses called `response_discursion`:

| ID_ResponseDiscursion | ID_ResponseDiscursion | TEXT_Response |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ............... |
| 2 | 1 | ............... |
| 3 | 2 | ............... |

All I'm trying to do is bring in all the questions from the `discursion` table, and add up the **total responses** for each question from the `response_discursion` table that is pegged to `ID_Discursion`.

For that I'm trying the following:

```
SELECT D.ID_Discursion, 
       D.TEXT_Discursion, 
       Total_Response = 
         (
          SELECT COUNT(RD.ID_ResponseDiscursion) 
          FROM response_discursion AS RD 
          ON RD.ID_Discursion = D.ID_Discursion
         ) 
FROM discursion AS D;
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Would you show us your expected result, please? And please describe what doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Schwern thanks for you response, but you already solve my problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the response table and then group by the discursion id. Use a left join if you want to see discursions with no responses.

```
select
  d.ID_Discursion,
  d.TEXT_Discursion,
  count(rd.ID_ResponseDiscursion) as Total_Response
from discursion d
left join response_discursion rd ON rd.ID_Discursion = d.ID_Discursion
group by d.ID_Discursion
```

Note: Normally you need every non-aggregated selected column in the group by. However, there's no need to have text_discursion in the group by because it is unique to each id_discursion.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/lMm_RAw3).

Comment: this is cool, didnt know that in Postgres, we could use group by without aggregation on cases where Primary Key is included, and other columns. Does this work for all data types?

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph It's not about data types. You can use the ungrouped TEXT_Discursion because its primary key is grouped.